# Recursive function to open branches in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a structure (list) composed by other values and structures, where the last has values and other structures and so on. Basically, it's a html parser in which I will retrieve some table data.

What I need to do is to reach all those branches and gather the desired values inside of them. So, I guess this is best done with a recursive function (here called openStructure).

Here's the html parser:

```
def getPage(item):
url = ''
round_url = f'{url}{item}'
page = requests.get(round_url)
return BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
```

Here I get the table columns desired as vectors:

```
def getTable(page):
table = page.find("table", id="customers")
cod = []
qt = []
un = []
typ = []
iRow = 0
checkRows = table.find_all('tr')
if checkRows:
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        iColumn = 0
        for column in row.find_all('td'):
            if iRow > 0:
                parser = column.text.split()
                if iColumn == 0:
                    cod.append(parser[0])
                if iColumn == 1:
                    length = len(parser)
                    typ.append(parser[length-1])
                    un.append(parser[length-2])
                    qt.append(parser[length-3])
            iColumn += 1
        iRow += 1
return cod, qt, un, typ
```

Here I gather all MO type itens and append it's respective code and quantity in the vectors:

```
def getMO(cod, qt, un, typ):
aux_mo_index = 0
mo_index = []
for mo in typ:
    if mo == 'MO':
        mo_index += [aux_mo_index]
    aux_mo_index += 1

mo_cod = []
mo_qt = []
i_index = 0
for i in mo_index:
    aux_mo = cod[i]
    if aux_mo in mo_cod:
        mo_qt[i_index] += qt[i_index]
    else:
        mo_cod.append(aux_mo)
        mo_qt.append(qt[i])
    i_index += 1
return mo_cod, mo_qt
```

Here I check for other structures inside that structure:

```
def getStructures(cod, qt, un, typ):
sp_index = []
aux_sp_index = 0
for sp in typ:
    if sp == 'SP':
        sp_index += [aux_sp_index]
    aux_sp_index += 1

structure = []
if not sp_index:
    return 0
else:        
    for i in sp_index:
        structure.append(cod[i])
    return structure
```

And here, finally, I want to open all structures and sum MO types according to its respective code:

```
def openStructure(id, mo_cod, mo_qt):
cod, qt, un, typ = getTable(getPage(id))
x, y = getMO(cod, qt, un, typ)
mo_cod += x
mo_qt += y
structures_left = getStructures(cod, qt, un, typ)

if not structures_left:
    return mo_cod, mo_qt
else:
    for i in structures_left:
        return openStructure(i, mo_cod, mo_qt)
```

But it seems to not work properly (just the openStructure function). Would anyone help me to fix its recursivity?

Examples of inputs/outputs:

getTable() output:

> ['00200190', '00120173', '00200189', '00200188', '00120174', '00120172', 'MO0004', 'MO0003', 'MO0002', 'MO0001']

> ['2,0000', '1,0000', '1,0000', '1,0000', '3,0000', '2,0000', '1,0000', '1,0000', '1,0000', '3,0000']

> ['PC', 'PC', 'PC', 'PC', 'PC', 'PC', 'HR', 'HR', 'HR', 'HR']

> ['SP', 'SP', 'SP', 'SP', 'SP', 'SP', 'MO', 'MO', 'MO', 'MO']

getMO() output:

> ['MO0004', 'MO0003', 'MO0002', 'MO0001']
> ['1,0000', '1,0000', '1,0000', '3,0000']

getStructures() output:

> ['00200190', '00120173', '00200189', '00200188', '00120174', '00120172']

Comment: Can your show some example of input data?

Comment: I'm using BeautifulSoap to read a html table where columns code and quantity are represented by cod and qt. The function getStructures analyses the column type for other structures inside this main structure. In case there are other structures, it should go over again to this openStructure function where it will sum all itens that aren't structures and open next structures till there is no structure left.

I will edit my post with the whole code and example of input data

Comment: That `for i in structures_left:` loop is pointless, since you immediately return the results from the first recursive call.  You would need to accumulate the results from *all* of the recursive calls, then return that after the loop.